# After System Restore, Windows 7 does not recognize one of my two HDDs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I did system restore from safe mode because otherwise I kept getting stuck on the startup screen.

This is what Disk Management shows:

[image: 1]

Comment: "does not recognize" how exactly? Does it show up in Disk Management?

Comment: Doesn't show up in My Computer.

Comment: right click on "Computer", select Manage.  Go to the section "Disk Management" and on the left side see if the disk shows up (at the bottom).  If it does, it will likely say something like "offline" or "foreign disk"  if so you should be able to right click on it and either bring it "online" or "import foreign disk".  Once you do that, you MIGHT have to assign it a drive letter, (right click on the volume and use the "change drive letter and path" option to specify the drive letter for the drive.  (Usually e: or something like that)..

Comment: @SwanWhisperer: You didn't answer my question about Disk Management. Do what Mike said above and let us know the results.

Comment: It does not seem to appear at all in Disk Management. in Disk Management I can see OS(C:) 679GB, RECOVERY 19.53, and another 102MB which seems to have no name. I have a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Ee6SJSC.png.

Comment: @SwanWhisperer: Use `@name` or else no-one gets notified of your comment. Does the drive show up in the BIOS at least?

Comment: @Karan: It does not show up in the BIOS.

Comment: Looks like an unfortunate drive failure that coincided with System Restore. You can try swapping cables or see if the drive is detected on another PC, but if it's not even detected by the BIOS then there's not much you can do really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in the past when re-installing Windows onto a DELL laptop. The solution for me was downloading the drivers manually and loading them in when Windows setup displayed drive / partition options.

Comment: I've downloaded the driver manually and it has helped in the sense that after running the updated driver I can now get into Windows normally. However, Windows Explorer still does not recognize my second HDD and nor does Disk Management. How did you get around this problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response on this one. Do you have a 2nd physical hard drive installed or are you referring to the recovery partition on drive c:?