# What does this BSOD error message mean?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    3081

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   4e
  BCP1: 0000000000000007
  BCP2: 000000000043BCE3
  BCP3: 0000000000000001
  BCP4: 0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  768_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\071213-4096414-01.dmp
  C:\Users\swanwhisperer\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-4260558-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: 4e = PFN_LIST_CORRUPT. Parameter 1 = 0x07 = A driver has unlocked a certain page more times than it locked it. I need the dmp file to see the causing driver.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you for your reply! Here is a link to the dmp file: http://www1.zippyshare.com/v/57496152/file.html. If you prefer it be sent via a different site please let me know.

Comment: ok, I got the dump and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, looks like the Intel Storage driver causes this bugcheck (BSOD):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PFN_LIST_CORRUPT (4e)
Typically caused by drivers passing bad memory descriptor lists (ie: calling
MmUnlockPages twice with the same list, etc).  If a kernel debugger is
available get the stack trace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000007, A driver has unlocked a page more times than it locked it
Arg2: 000000000043bce3, page frame number
Arg3: 0000000000000001, current share count
Arg4: 0000000000000000, 0

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x4E_7

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF80000BA0FB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002441a83 to fffff80002479c00

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!IopfCompleteRequest
iaStor
0x0
0x0
0x0


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
iaStor+293e0
fffff880`0105f3e0 ??              ???

IMAGE_NAME:  iaStor.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x4E_7_iaStor+293e0

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x4E_7_iaStor+293e0

    Loaded symbol image file: iaStor.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\iaStor.sys
    Image name: iaStor.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Jan 13 02:50:12 2011
```

So use the latest driver from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2101&DwnldID=22676&keyword=Intel%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology%20%28Intel%20RST%29&lang=eng) and not the [older driver which Dell offers for your XPS 17 (L702X)](ftp://ftp.dell.com/pages/Drivers/xps-l702x.html#Serial%20ATA).

Comment: This has had a dramatic effect in that now I can run Windows normally without any troubles. However, my second HDD still does not appear in My Computer. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: IMO this answer would be greatly improved if you were to explain how you went from the dump file to the above fairly readable dump, and which tools might allow someone else to do it. As it stands, this answer doesn't really help anyone but the OP.

Comment: @SwanWhisperer is the HDD detected in the BIOS/UEFI? You should create a new question about it.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling  open the dump in **Windbg** and run **analyze -v**

Comment: @magicandre1981: His second HDD [isn't being detected by the BIOS](http://superuser.com/questions/617444/after-system-restore-windows-7-does-not-recognize-one-of-my-two-hdds#comment768848_617444), and don't ask him to create a new question since he's created two already for it: [1](http://superuser.com/questions/617444/after-system-restore-windows-7-does-not-recognize-one-of-my-two-hdds), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/618488/how-can-i-make-windows-7-recognize-my-second-hdd-again).

Comment: @Karan ok, I haven't looked if he already did this.